# Is the construction unsigned long long permitted?

Tags: c++, types, casting

Is the construction `unsigned long long` permitted?
And is there anything like `unsigned long double`?

Comment: Have you given it a try?

Comment: Floating point types are never `unsigned`.

Comment: Giving it a try not necissarily is a good option: Compilers sometimes provide extended types which are non-standard.

Comment: @johannes Yes, but *not* giving it a try before asking is not any better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`unsigned long long` is fine. (Technically, it's been around since C99, but only since C++11, but every major C++ compiler has been implementing it for quite a long time already.)

There is no such thing as `unsigned long double`. Floating point types (at least those available in any language I can think of, and certainly those described by IEEE754 and the C standard) are always signed.

Comment: The C spec explicitly says that there are no unsigned floating-point types.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `unsigned long long` is permitted because it declares a variable of type `long long` that is also `unsigned`. The `unsigned` keyword can be applied to any integer type, and `long long` is indeed an integer type.

There is no such thing as `unsigned long double` because `long double` is a floating point type (as opposed to an integer type), and there is no such thing as unsigned floating point types ([reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512022/why-doesnt-c-have-unsigned-floats), [reference 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589663/why-no-unsigned-floating-point-types)).

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) here, there is a`unsigned long long` but only in `C++ 11`. About `unsigned long double` I am not sure.
Check out the reference,

Comment: ... yeah, but it's been in C since `C99` and every major C++ compiler has been implementing it for years even though it wasn't in the standard until `C++11`.