# Why overloading causes ambiguous call if unsigned is used?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
void foo(int,int) {}
void foo(int ,float) {}
void foo(float,int) {}

void main()
{
  unsigned int i = 10;
  unsigned float f = 1.0;       //line 5
  foo(i,f); // ambiguous call error
}
```

replacing line 5 by

```
float f = 1.0;
```

makes the program work. Why is it so?

I am working on visual studio 2005.

Comment: What kind of data type is `unsigned float`?

Comment: compiler is neither showing error nor warning.this is making me confused also.any clue?

Comment: Well, it is a 6 year old compiler. You should use a newer version unless someone is forcing you to use VS2005. Visual Studio has a free version call Express Edition, google it and download the 2010 version. Or there is always MinGW (it's free too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such data type as `unsigned float`. Pay attention to compiler warnings; if you're not getting any bump up the warning level. From running this example on Visual Studio 2010 it looks like the compiler ignores the `float` keyword in the declaration

```
unsigned float f = 1.0;
```

This makes `f` an `unsigned int`. Since you don't have an overload of `foo()` that takes an `int` and `unsigned int` the compiler is unable to deduce which overload to call. If you add another overload

```
void foo(int,unsigned int) {}
```

the ambiguous call error disappears.

Comment: then it should call foo(int,int) as unsigned int is promoted to int instead of showing ambiguity

Comment: @Suri: unsigned int to int is not a promotion since the latter has a smaller range than the former

Comment: yes u r right.so does it means that conversion from unsigned int to int or float have same priority when overloding function are resolved?It is not like that unsigned int to int have higher priority

Answer (score 3):

Conversion from `unsigned int` to either `int` or `float` results in a loss of precision, and both are considered equal by the compiler. You have to add an explicit case to make the compiler decide which to use, e.g.:

```
foo(i, static_cast<float>(f));
```

Note that there is no such thing as `unsigned float`. If the compiler accepts that, it is not standards-compliant (VC2010 warns about it, not sure about VC2005).

---

The relevant sections of the C++98 standard are section 4, which ranks a numeric type cast as either an exact match, a promotion, or a conversion, and section 13.3.3.2, which defines how implicit conversions are ranked for overload resolution. The latter section states, in subparagraph 4:

> Standard conversion sequences are ordered by their ranks: an Exact Match is a better conversion than a Promotion, which is a better conversion than a Conversion.

Conversion from `unsigned int` to either `float` or `int` is ranked as "Conversion" either way, so it is "indistinguishable", making the overload ambiguous.

Since `unsigned float` is not an actual type according to the standard, it's hard to say how this applies in your situation, but your compiler appears to treat conversion from `unsigned float` to either `float` or `int` as indistinguishable too.

Answer (score 0):

When you make f float there is only one function that can be called - so no ambiguity. It works, because unsigned int can be cast to int silently.

Comment: but why it is causing problem for unsigned float?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of type is `unsigned float`?? Nothing that I've ever heard of. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/512022/why-doesnt-c-have-unsigned-floats).

As far as I understand, floating point types (i.e. `float`, `double` etc) are always signed.

EDIT: This will not compile at ideone (which is gcc 4.3.4) (it throws the error "invalid signed/unsigned with float"):

```
int main()
{
    unsigned float ff = 1.0;

    return ff;
}
```

I dunno what MSVC is doing if it accepts `unsigned float`. I don't think it's a valid type.

Comment: compiler is neither showing error nor warning.this is making me confused also.any clue?