# float32 between (0, 1) optimization for wireless transmission

Tags: optimization, data-structures, types, mathematical-optimization

I'm looking for a way to optimize `float32` value, that contains only values from `(0, 1)` for wireless transfer.

[image]

Since in my case all values are positive, I've already trimmed *Sign bit*, but now I need some help

I think, that my next step is going to be trimming all *Fraction* trailing zeroes zeros, and then, somehow optimize *Exponent* part

But I'm not quite sure, maybe there is already some bit-level optimizations exists for same cases, since using `float32` to store values between `(0, 1)` is very common practice

Data integrity and error correction are not relevant in my case

Comment: there was exactly a question like yours in the past but I couldn't find it now. The answer is you can, but you'll get only 1 more bit from the exponent (because half the representable values are in the range `[0, 1)` and the remaining are in `[1, ∞)`), or you'll get a larger range. For unsigned float you can use a trick like this [Storing non-negative floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64869420/995714)

Comment: You could try to use fixed-point precision. It would be cleaner and simpler than hacking IEEE754 32-bit floats. The downside is that the precision near zero is less good while fixed-point precision benefit from a better overall precision in average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I've decided to just use `uint16_t`, where `0=0f` and `65365=1f`, which is enough for me. But at memory level I'm not actually using float at all. This integer-based logic helped me not only achieve shorter byte sequence for wireless transfer, but also use less memory

Other option is to use `uint32_t`, that will use the same amount amount of bits

Conversion to float, if you need it, is smth like this:

```cpp
float to_float = (float) value / (float) UINT16_MAX
```