# Javascript bit shift to 32 bits

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

I have an array of ints

```
var ints = [R,B,G,A]
```

and I want to use shifting to get a 32-bit representation

```
var thirtyTwo = AGBR
```

so for example,

```
[255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0] => 0xFF0000FF => 4278190335
```

I'm attempting to do this with a loop and bitshift:

```
function cArrayToABGR(va) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < va.length; ++i) {
        var color = va[i];
        color <<= (8 * i);
        res += color;
    }
    return res;
}
```

But the main problem is when I bitshift 255.0 << 24, I get a negative number

```
255.0 << 24 = -16777216
```

which tells me I either hit a bit limit or the res is signed. I thought all bitwise operations in Javascript are on unsigned 32 bit floats, so not sure what's going on here. Help?

Comment: "I thought all bitwise operations in Javascript are on unsigned 32 bit floats" - signed 32-bit integers in two's complement  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In JS all bitwise operators are signed 32bit, whereas your result is unsigned 32bit.

As a workaround you could calculate it as:

```
var res = ints.reduce(function(result, current) {
    return result * 256 + current;
}, 0); // 4278190335
```

which is even nicer in ES2015:

```
var res = ints.reduce((result, current) => result * 256 + current, 0);
```

PS: not sure if a thing like "unsigned float" even exists somewhere (at least for the languages that implement IEEE754)

Comment: Re your PS, [Why doesn't C have unsigned floats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/512022/why-doesnt-c-have-unsigned-floats).

Comment: Answer below works better. Just add >>>0 to the end of your line to make everything unsigned and fix the mess.

Comment: @opcode if you check comments to the other answer you may see that it's me suggested them to use `>>> 0` :-D

Answer (score 6):

`<<` works on signed 32-bit integers, while [`>>>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) is [unsigned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift), so you can use `>>> 0` to get an unsigned integer:

```
(255 << 24) >>> 0 // 4278190080
```

**So:**

```
var ints = [255.0, 0.0, 0.0, 255.0];

function cArrayToABGR(va) {
    var res = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < va.length; ++i) {
        var color = va[i];
        color <<= (8 * i);
        res += color;
    }
    return res >>> 0;
}

console.log(cArrayToABGR(ints));
// 4278190335
```

Comment: Or even `return res >>> 0;`

Comment: Ah yeah, better yet. Thanks.

Comment: No idea why is this not accepted answer as this solves the problem in original question without any hacks.